# brew install php70 with package

Tags: macos, installation, php, homebrew

Sorry for this simple question, but I search a lot, I don't know how to do that.

I installed the php70 with another package

```
$ brew install php70
```

I found this option

```
$ brew info php70
...
--with-phpdbg
    Enable building of the phpdbg SAPI executable (PHP 5.4 and above)
```

and I try to search it about phpdbg. I can't find it.

```
$ brew search php70
```

so I type this command, it's failed, because I installed the php70.

```
$ brew install php70 --with-phpdbg
```

The only way is reinstall?

```
$ brew reinstall php70 --with-phpdbg
```

Comment: Can you share your relevant error messages as well?

Comment: I don't have any error message, I just want enable phpdbg.

Comment: And the last command worked for you fine? If so, then when you want to recompile PHP with other option, you've to reinstall it. What's the problem then using the last reinstall command?